# Casting to generic Version of Class ends in InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, class, generics, casting

I'm trying to cache some classes in a List.

Because this class has a generic Property, I created a none-generic Type of the class which is the Type of this List.

So my BOs looks like this:

```
public class Model<T> : Model where T : class
{
    public T Cls
    {
        get { return (T) ClsObject; }
        set { ClsObject = value; }
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public List<ModelProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public Type ClsType { get; set; }
    public object ClsObject { get; set; }
}
```

So here's the Caching-Class:

```
private static List<Model> CachedModels {get; set;}

public static Model<T> GetCachedVersion<T>(this T cls) where T : class
{
    var ret = CachedModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ClsType == typeof(T));
    return ret != null ? (Model<T>)ret : null;
}
```

But the casting from the GetCachedVersion-Method crashes and I don't understand why.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: There's nothing indicating that every `Model` with a `ClsType` of `T` is actually a `Model<T>`. We have no idea how you're creating models... and heck, `ClsType` is even settable. There are any number of reasons this could be wrong.

Comment: What is the actual (runtime) type of `ret`?

Comment: Thanks Jon for the hint. I extraced an Interface from Model, so now my BOs are Model<T> : IModel and Model : IModel. Still not working...

And Thomas: Thank you too. ret is the Model of Model<T> - that part of the code is working fine.

Comment: can you show the code that sets ClsType? btw the way you are using it it shouldn't be settable because it's tied to the type of the object and therefor not state of the object

Comment: oh and what's the type of the object you call this extension method on?

Comment: You should check if ClsType actually fits to what is in ClsObject. I suggest that ClsType should be a computes Property from ClsObject and checked if it fits to your T generic parameter. Seems ambigous to me to have those properties and a not dependent generic parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the first object of type `Model<T>` you could change your code to

```
public static Model<T> GetCachedVersion<T>(this T cls) where T : class
{
    return CachedModels.OfType<T>.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

There are a number of things you might wish to consider. Because if things were as you expected them to be your code should work no different from this.

1) tie the `ClsType` to the `ClsObject` or `T`
2) remove the setter (or otherwise hide it from external code) of `ClsObject` since it violates the invariant of `Cls`. You can set the `Cls` property to something that's not a `T`

```
 public class Model {
    public List<ModelProperty> Properties { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public virtual Type ClsType { get {
           ClsObject.GetType();
    } }
    public object ClsObject { get; protected set; }
}

public class Model<T> : Model {
     public override Type ClsType { get{
      return typeof(T);
     }}

     public T Cls
    {
        get { return (T) ClsObject; }
        set { ClsObject = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1st guesses:

1. Are you by any chance using a nullable type anywhere in your code like Model?
2. See if you are setting `ClsType` properly.

Comment: Thanks Kaveh. ret is the correct value, it's the downcast which seams to be the problem.

Comment: There's a restriction on class so the type parameter will always point to classes and `Model<T>` being a class it self pretty much makes all the types in question classes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would have to create a Helper-Class which created the generic Type through reflections. There's no other way to downcast besides hardcode it.